# Wrap elements into div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would need to wrap some HTML elements into div.

The markup is something like this:

```
<div class="block">
    <h2 class="block-title">Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque <span>tellus</span> non magna.</p>
    <div class="message"><span class="message-title">Warning:</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <strong>magna</strong>.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2 class="block-title">Lorem 2 lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <div class="note"><span class="note-title">Warning:</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <a href="#">magna</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The end result what I need it to be is:

```
<div class="block">
    <h2 class="block-title">Lorem</h2>
    <div class="collapsed">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque <span>tellus</span> non magna.</p>
        <div class="message"><span class="message-title">Warning:</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <strong>magna</strong>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2 class="block-title">Lorem 2 lorem</h2>
    <div class="collapsed">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div class="note"><span class="note-title">Warning:</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <a href="#">magna</a>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically everything that is inside  and after h2.block-title should go inside .

My current JS

```
$('.block').each(function() {
    $(this).find('p').wrapAll('<div class="collapsable"></div>');
});
```

But this works only for p tags. How can I add also divs included?

Comment: I'd use `$(this).children(':not(h2)').wrapAll('<div class="collapsable"></div>');` or `$(this).children(':not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div class="collapsable"></div>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[comma(`,`) separated multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**, Also you need to use **[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** else it will select inner elements also

```js
$('.block').each(function() {
  $(this).children('p,div').wrapAll('<div class="collapsable"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <h2 class="block-title">Lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque <span>tellus</span> non magna.</p>
  <div class="message"><span class="message-title">Warning:</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <strong>magna</strong>.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <h2 class="block-title">Lorem 2 lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <div class="note"><span class="note-title">Warning:</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <a href="#">magna</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or select all elements except `h2` using **[`:not(h2)`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

```js
$('.block').each(function() {
  $(this).children(':not(h2)').wrapAll('<div class="collapsable"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <h2 class="block-title">Lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque <span>tellus</span> non magna.</p>
  <div class="message"><span class="message-title">Warning:</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <strong>magna</strong>.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <h2 class="block-title">Lorem 2 lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <div class="note"><span class="note-title">Warning:</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Phasellus fringilla, lorem in congue lacinia, metus dolor mollis diam, eget maximus neque tellus non <a href="#">magna</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First suggestions doesn't work as it would also take out paragraphs inside note/message. But the not(h2) works perfectly!  I will change find to children though :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to select everythig inside `div.block` without header. That can be done in different ways:

- select exact tags (if you decide to add html elements, you'll have to change js also)

  ```
  $('.block').find('div,p');
  ```
- select all and subtract header

  ```
  $('.block').find(':not(h1)');
  ```
- select everything near header

  ```
  $('.block').find('h1').siblings();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`$('.block-title').each(function(){
  $(this).siblings().wrapAll('<div class="collapsable"></div>');
})`

Comment: You should add some explanation why you propose this exact solution. This post is now not of good enough quality and might be deleted by reviewers soon. Example: You need to apply to the `h2` element, not the div, because ...

Comment: It is the correct solution of problem. I don't think there is any problem in this.